# "Activate" python environment should activate the kernel in that environment, yes?

Tags: anaconda, kernel, conda, environment, activation

If I create a conda environment using py 3.5 and then activate that environment, why does conda perceive that I am using python 3.8 for package installation purposes? Is there way to activate the environment AND activate the python 3.5 kernel at once? (I honestly thought that was what the environment was for, but that seems to be the observed behavior of "activate".)

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3_Sep2020> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3
hddm_py35                C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3\envs\hddm_py35
hddm_py35b               C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3\envs\hddm_py35b

(base) PS C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3_Sep2020> activate hddm_py35b
(base) PS C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3_Sep2020> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3
hddm_py35                C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3\envs\hddm_py35
hddm_py35b               C:\Users\Peter\anaconda3\envs\hddm_py35b
```

I'm guess from the asterisk on (base) that activate didn't work at all.

If I want to *activate hddm_py35b* what command should I issue?

Answer (score 0):

The conda cheatsheet (first hit on googling this question)

1. gives an inaccurate syntax, and
2. fails silently.

The correct syntax is

```
conda activate hddm_35b
```

Conda is still just a baby, and its growing pains are evident.